# How to create 'Drawn' style line around items in menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a menu for wordpress, and i'm trying to get a
"drawn"like border arround the different menu items.

As for now i have one background with a 'drawn' circle. (let's call it bg.png).

I can get the circle around a menu item and place it right. But ofcourse some
of my menu item words are longer than the others.

This is how i use the active part of the menu right now:

```
url('img/bg.png'); 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position-y: 10;
```

This shows the circle when hovering the menu items, but on some words its too
big or too small. This is something like the png i'm using: http://instantsplash.com/a/images/hand-drawn/circles/04.png

thanks in advance!

Comment: use border and border radius css?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a previous work.

You have to decide whether you want a big image that can be too large on certain items or a small that can sometimes overlap your item if the text is larger.

The other solution is to use the `background-size` property in css and stretch your image to the size of your container. But this solution can lead to ratio or image quality problem.

Comment: This means i should make a specific bg class for every menu item right?

Comment: No you can target all menu items with one single css selector, for exemple `.menu a{css code here}` or `.menu li{css code here}`.
Then using `background-size:100% 100%;` your image should be able to stretch to the size of the element.

Comment: I forgot you wanted the circle to appear on hover, so the selector will look something like this `menu li:hover{css code here}`

Answer (score 0):

One of the option could be if you can use javascript/jQuery to measure the size of the hovered element than you can adjust the size 'drawn' circle image.

```
$('li.menu-items').hover(function(){
   $(this).addClass('hovered').css('background-size', $(this).width());
},function(){
   $(this).removeClass('hovered');
})
```

Comment: This seems nice, i'll try if i can get this working!